# Clear ALL clipboard entries

Tags: android, clipboard

On my Samsung Tab 3 running Android 4.1.2 multiple copies to clipboard produce a clipboard containing each copy.  This is seen through a button on the tight bottom of the slide-up keyboard.

I'd like to delete all these copies programmatically, however, the ClipboardManager doesn't appear to offer methods to do this.  How can delete everything that has been copied to the clipboard?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 15):

`ClipboardManager clipService = (ClipboardManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);`
`ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");`

`clipService.setPrimaryClip(clipData);`

Comment: @VladimirIvanov have you got any solution form same?

Comment: this doesn't clear any clip item from the clipboard's history. you can verify by using a keyboard that has clipboard history support such as Google Gboard

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can.  It sounds like Samsung has written a clipboard extender that monitors clipboard events and retains a copy of everything.

There is no way to access the history without (the user) interacting with the history list via the UI.

One possible work-around:  If the history list is of the limited/recycling variety (i.e. limited to 10 with new items overwriting old items), then you may be able to effectively erase it by repeatedly sending blank strings (or harmless non-duplicate strings such as 'empty1', 'empty2', etc..)
Whatever you do, you'll end up overwriting something that the user has deemed to be important, and **THE USER WILL HATE YOU**.

Answer (score 3):

From API 28

```
ClipboardManager mCbm = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
mCbm.clearPrimaryClip()
```

Comment: It has no effect unfortunately. And I'm on API 31.

Answer (score 0):

Using the manager you mentioned, you can set an empty string to it with [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) to clear the clipboard.

```
ClipboardManager mClipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
mClipboardManager.setText("");
```

Comment: This adds a blank clip to the stack.  The sensitive data previously copied remains available for all to see. That's what I'd like to delete.

Comment: And what about adding the empty String as a Clip? `ClipData data = mClipboardManager.newPlainText("", "");
mClipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(data);`

Answer (score 0):

To actually delete the entries (instead of exchanging them with an empty string via setPrimaryClip()), with API level 28+:

```
ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
while (clipboardManager.hasPrimaryClip()) {
    clipboardManager.clearPrimaryClip()
}
```