# How to clear Android clipboard?

Tags: android, clipboard

None of the methods I found worked.

Here is what I tried :

1/ Using `clearPrimaryClip()` method of `ClipboardManager` class

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
clipboard.clearPrimaryClip();
```

This doesn't do anything. The clipboard still holds my old item.

2/ Using the suggestions from stackoverflow

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", " ");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

This one only adds an empty clipboard item to the list of items. The old clipboard item is not cleared or removed.

Is there a programmatic way to delete an item from the clipboard item list?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user167698 There is no way to do this programmatically, at least for Android versions which support multiple clips in the clipboard (starting Android 4.4.2 ?). With older versions, which couldn't contain more than 1 clip in the clipboard, setting the data of the clip to " " did the trick, but this does not work anymore. Cheers

Comment: Kaspersky Password App can do that, so it is possible. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: @ElMostafaIDRASSI does this question have the answer you were looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/28353981/3590155

Comment: If you found out how to achieve that, I'm insterested too.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply send multiple empty values to the clipboar:

```
(requireActivity().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager).apply {
    for (i in 1..50) {
        setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText(null, ""))
    }
}
```